# Which sutta is it in which Sariputta asks his disciples .. friend if someone asks, is the world eternal

Tags: pali-canon, reference-request, suttas, sariputta

I remember reading once, disciples of Sariputta were going out into the world and he ask them the question: "Friend what if someone ask you is the world eternal or is not eternal". Then his passed his disciples when they just quote Dependent Origination "depending on contact, feeling arises, depending on feeling, craving arises..etc..

I'm trying to look for that sutta again. Anybody know which sutta is it or my memory has been corrupted, there never was such a sutta.

Answer (score 1):

I found two that are similar, but not identical.

The *[Kalara Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn12.32)* is similar, in that it's Sariputta talking about Dependent Origination. However, in that sutta, it's the Buddha who is asking the questions; Sariputta has no disciples; and instead of asking whether the world is eternal, the question is whether birth is ended. This could perhaps be the one you're thinking of, because the Buddha asks questions like, "But, Sāriputta, if they were to ask you ..."

Or there's the *[The Greater Discourse on the
Elephant-Footprint Simile](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh101.pdf)*, which starts with Sariputta addressing the bhikkus as "Friends", and ends by repeating that "He who sees dependent origination sees the
Teaching; he who sees the Teaching sees dependent origination."

Comment: If you want to add to this answer, SN 22.2 is the only example I can find of Sariputta addressing monks taking leave of Sariputta.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, but not the one I'm looking for__@yuttadhammo Thanks, but not it.

Comment: SN 22.2 is the [Devadaha Sutta: At Devadaha](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.002.than.html). In summary I think it teaches renunciation or dispassion, especially dispassion for the skandhas, because they're subject to change.